# Selecting multiple items from card responses in dialogflow

Tags: node.js, heroku, dialogflow-es

```
Agent:  I have made a note, Now can you please indicate which all parts of the vehicle were damaged in the accident?
User:   Windshield/Bumper/Front Side/Rear/Hood(Card response)
```

In the above chat script, I am presenting the user with card response to select parts of a vehicle. A user can select any number of parts. I want to implement it with Dialogflow card responses. How to implement this? Help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should consult the [Rich Messages](https://dialogflow.com/docs/rich-messages) page of the documentation and look for docs on the specific integration that you want to do in order to find the correct way to add suggestion chips or some type of response.